# redirecting a url to a subfolder using AliasMatch and/or htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following set up and my domain (assume abc.com) points to src

```
src
    index.php
    blog
        index.php
```

I want to redirect all requests to *abc.com/blog* to be served from *src/blog* folder and rest from src folder. Both src and blog have other directories as well and both use routing to index.php to serve pages.

The problem is that urls like *abc.com/blog/whatever* go to *src/index.php* whereas it should go to *blog/index.php*
editing *src/.htaccess* is not working because I have to direct the request to a sub directory.
The following diective:

```
AliasMatch  /blog.* /path/to/blog
```

leads to loop redirection:
abc.com/blog/whatever/index.php/index.php/index.php....

I followed the explanation here:
http://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?t=1566

and it says Apache will add index.php if we give a directory path in alias target.

Requirement is simple: just throw all blog/* requests in blog folder and htaccess should handle the rest

Answer (score 1):

Try this rule in `/blog/.htaccess` as your **first rule**:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /src/$1 [L]
```

Comment: does not work... abc.com/blog/whatever still goes to src/index.php

Comment: `abc.com/blog/whatever` should goto `abc.com/src/blog/whatever` as per this. Are there any more rules in this .htaccess OR is there any .htaccess in `/blog/` folder?

Comment: blog uses url rewriting and has its own htaccess. "whatever" is not a directory - it is supposed to go to blog/index.php but is not - that is the main problem I am having.

Comment: Ok post your .htaccess from `/blog/` folder.

Comment: still not working... I get the following error now: _The requested URL /src/ was not found on this server_ blog's htaccess is a standard wordpress haccess:`RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
`

Comment: You never told about the wordpress before. WP is quite rigid about rewriting stuff.

Comment: i dont think this is related to wordpress. control is not reaching the blog's index.php at all.

Comment: you were right. WP's htaccess was the culprit. I needed to change the last line to `RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]` Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
<Directory /usr/local/www/apache>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

    RewriteRule ^blog/.*$ /blog/index.php [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [NC,L]
</Directory>
```

I put this in the apache config file. I have thrown away the AliasMatch and .htaccess files.

Comment: does not work... abc.com/blog/whatever still goes to src/index.php instead of blog/index.php